# Streaming JSON parser with fopen(), fgets() and PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, fopen, fgets

A snippet of the JSON file.

```
{ 
"products": { 
"product" : [
{ "name" : "Desktop", "price" : 799.99, "memory" : "4GB"},
{ "name" : "Laptop", "price" : 999.99, "memory" : "3GB"},
{ "name" : "Notebook", "price" : 899.99, "memory" : "2GB"}
] }}
```

I need to parse a very large JSON file, then display relevant search results based on user queries. I want to avoid loading the entire file into memory with json_decode or file_get_contents, and instead parse the file line by line.

```
$search_results = "";
$Json_file = fopen("products.json", "r");
while (!feof($Json_file)) {
$line_of_data .= fgets($Json_file);
$decoded_line = json_decode($line_of_data);
```

At this point I want to use an if statement so that the fgets() function only pulls data from the JSON file that has a "price" value of under 900. The if statement below is not working - it causes the page to be completely blank, but the code works fine without the if statement. My question is: is there a "performance-friendly" way to code an if statement (at this point in the code) so irrelevant JSON data can be filtered out and not placed in the search_results variable below? Or is there a better way to parse a large JSON file line by line in a "performance-friendly" manner?

```
if ($decoded_line->products->product->price < 900) {  //assuming a site visitor is searching for an item under $900
$search_results .= decoded_line->products->product;
}
}
```

By filtering out irrelevant JSON data in the if statement above, I assume it would help overall performance when we use json_decode right here.

```
$data = json_decode($search_results);
$product = $data->products->product;

foreach($product as $Product) {
echo $Product->name . " " . $Product->price;
echo "<br>";
}

fclose($Json_file);
```

Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to write the JSON to a local database (if it isn't already) and use ajax calls and onkeychange events to return search results in a filtered manner?

Comment: I want to avoid ajax and anything else that is client side oriented. My main goal is to filter out the irrelevant data (from the JSON file) early on so that there is less for JSON_decode to decode (later in the code)

Comment: You could still filter it through a db tho?

Comment: Is there a way to filter without a database (IE in the code where I attempted to filter with the if statement)?

Comment: There is using array manipulation. Parse the JSON into an array and then you can compare, sort etc but the only way I see of getting it where you can work on it with out the whole dataset being in memory is to use a database. Unless of course you only need a small subset and dont have to keep querying the whole JSON file continually.